# How do I use Text.JSON.Generic with optional JSON fields?

Tags: json, haskell, data-binding

Is it possible to use `Text.JSON.Generic` with a JSON record type that includes optional fields?  I was hoping that this would "just work" if I declared the Haskell type as `Maybe a`, for example:

```
import Text.JSON.Generic

data Record = Record {
   myMandatoryField :: Integer,
   myOptionalField :: Maybe Integer
} deriving (Eq, Show, Data, Typeable)
```

but that doesn't do the right thing.

If it's not possible to make optional fields work with `Text.JSON.Generic`, is there an alternative Haskell-JSON data binding library that does work with optional fields?

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn't do the right thing` ? I think it should print null in json for `Nothing`

Comment: The behavior I'm expecting is as follows.  When parsing a JSON string: if the optional field is present, I expect `myOptionalField` to be `Just value`; if the field is not present, I expect `myOptionalField` to be `Nothing`.  When building a JSON string: if `myOptionalField` is `Just value` then I expect the field to be generated, with value `value`; if `myOptionalField` is `Nothing` then I expect the field not to be generated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue with Generics-based parsing. [Aeson](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson) has had the same issue and the maintainers have decided to deprecate that functionality in favor of a Template Haskell-based strategy: https://github.com/bos/aeson/issues/118

With Aeson, your code would look very similar:

```
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.TH

data Record = Record {
    myMandatoryField :: Integer,
    myOptionalField :: Maybe Integer
} deriving (Eq, Show)

$(deriveJSON id ''Record)
```

This way, the `Maybe` field encodes and decodes as expected:

```
$ ghci
λ :l Main.hs
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
λ encode $ Record 5 Nothing
"{\"myOptionalField\":null,\"myMandatoryField\":5}"
λ decode it :: Maybe Record
Just (Record {myMandatoryField = 5, myOptionalField = Nothing})
```

**UPDATE**: As mentioned in the comments, null-field omission is available with Template Haskell in Aeson HEAD, but that's not yet on Hackage. You can get that behavior today with hand-written `FromJSON`/`ToJSON` instances:

```
instance FromJSON Record where
    parseJSON = withObject "record" $ \o -> Record
        <$> o .: "myMandatoryField"
        <*> o .:? "myOptionalField"

instance ToJSON Record where
    toJSON (Record manf optf) = object $ catMaybes
        [ ("myMandatoryField" .=) <$> pure manf
        , ("myOptionalField" .=) <$> optf ]
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  However, it still doesn't give exactly the behavior I'd like, which is for the field not to appear at all (as opposed to being generated with a value of `null`).

Comment: This feature, I believe, is in Aeson HEAD but hasn't been released to Hackage yet.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you're looking for is available in Aeson HEAD by using the [new `deriveJSON :: Options -> Name -> Q [Dec]` TH generator](https://github.com/bos/aeson/blob/master/Data/Aeson/TH.hs). You can then set `, omitNothingFields = True` in an [`Options` struct](https://github.com/bos/aeson/blob/master/Data/Aeson/Types/Internal.hs).

Not sure what the schedule for the next Hackage release is.

Answer (score 1):

To update [J Abrahamson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476408/j-abrahamson) answer and for the sake of completeness: it is now possible to achieve that behavior by deriving `Generic` and customizing the default options as follows:

```
import           GHC.Generics

data Record = Record {
  myMandatoryField :: Integer,
  myOptionalField :: Maybe Integer
} deriving (Eq, Show, Generic)

instance FromJSON Record where
    parseJSON = genericParseJSON defaultOptions { omitNothingFields  = True }
```